# From there was onto Norfolk, Baltimore’s AAA team, where he experienced even worse results

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I read this sentence [on a webpage](http://riveraveblues.com/2009/09/a-little-bit-about-freddy-guzman-17143/).

> **From there was onto** Norfolk, Baltimore’s AAA team, where he
> experienced even worse results.

I can't understand the structure and meaning of the sentence.

Is the subject of the sentence '*From there*' as a single chunk?

If so, what is the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: Looks like an error to me; the writer probably meant to say _he went on to_.

Comment: More likely it was meant to be "from there it was onto Norfolk" which more or less means the same thing